# how to pass an class template argument

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a stack/queue based on user input and want to pass class and the data members of this class need to be pushed to stack.
Let me know how can this be achieved.
The line marked as this line in stack.cpp needs to be changed.

`stack.h`:

```
 template <class T>
/* Abstract class for stack n queue */
class StacknQueue
{
     //the code for stack n queue push/pop goes here
};
```

`stack.cpp`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stackqueue.h"

using namespace std;

class employee
{
public:
    char name[10];
public:
    void getname()
    { 
        cout << "enter name";
        cin >> name;
    }

};
void main()
{


    StacknQueue<employee> *e;
    Stack<employee> dStack;
    Queue<employee> dQueue;
    //employee e1;

    int input = 0;

    e = &dstack;
    //if(e->remove(e1.getname())) //----this line
    {
        cout << data << "\t";
    }
}
```

The line marked as this line I need to push the data that is fetched from class employee on to stack/queue.

Please help me in this.

Comment: It would be better to reduce the lines of code that you provide to the site. Users cannot dig into such an amount of code.

Comment: I don't understand what you need and the issue

Comment: I want to do operations push/pop on the data member read from class employee.i.e. I need to push the value that is read in getname member function of class employee.

Comment: e1.getName() returns void, so nothing can be removed. It looks very crude and maybe you need a better understanding of basic things.